# Carregar uma activity dentro de um fragment com tabHost

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-activity

Estou começando com o `android studio` lendo algumas coisas e assistindo alguns videos no youtube, basicamente o que pretendo fazer é um programa de calculo para facilitar minha vida no meu serviço, algumas contas simples que já consegui fazer (consegui apenas os cálculos), mas com alguns layouts péssimos.

Descobri essa `tabHost slide` com `fragments`, e gostei muito do resultado, simples e prático.

Criei então a partir de um tutorial esse app abaixo que cria as tabs, e ao clicar em cada uma (ou usar o "slide") ela me mostra o ID da tab, mas o que eu precisaria seria em vez de mostrar apenas um texto, carregar uma outra `activity` e manter a tab para um fácil acesso as outras.

Coloquei um `IF` para comparar se a `ID` da tab for "tal", carrega "tal" `activity`, até ai funcionou, mas nessa `activity` estava sem as tabs, então copiei todo o código das tabs da primeira `activity` para essa segunda, e ao clicar na segunda aba, vejo que ela carrega a nova `activity` (apenas o texto, nada das cores e layout) mas logo em seguida trava o app.

Sinceramente não entendi o que fiz de errado, cheguei a tentar até colocar um `FOR` e um `WHILE` para garantir que ela iria carregar apenas uma vez (pensei que estava travado ao carregar a segunda `activity` varias vezes) mas não mudou nada....

Alguém teria alguma luz por favor ?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.tbarata.myapplication;
import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity; import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity { private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1111", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2222", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3333", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab44").setIndicator("Tab 44", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab5").setIndicator("Tab 55", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab6").setIndicator("Tab 66", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
}
}
```

**activity_fragment_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#eaecee">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

**FragmentTab.java**

```
package com.example.tbarata.myapplication;
import android.os.Bundle; import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_layout, container, false);
     if (this.getTag() == "tab2") {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), fragment_layout2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
                        }
    } else {

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(this.getTag() + " Content");
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

e o **fragment_layout2.java**

```
public class fragment_layout2 extends FragmentActivity {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_layout2);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1111", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2222", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3333", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab44").setIndicator("Tab 44", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab5").setIndicator("Tab 55", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab6").setIndicator("Tab 66", null),
            FragmentTab.class, null);

}
```

Comment: O desenvolvimento Android evolui muito rapidamente. TabHost está considerado *deprecated*, em sua vez começou-se a usar *ActionBar tabs* que, com o surgimento do Android 5, passou também a *deprecated*. Se você está a começar agora evite usar coisas que já não se usam. Neste momento a forma de implementar *tabs* é utilizando TabLayout, veja [aqui](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout) como.

Comment: Muito obrigado @ramaral !, hoje estou meio enrolado, mas amanha mesmo já começo a estudar o TabLayout, muito obrigado mesmo pela dica! Fui no "embalo" por ver vários tutoriais do tabHost, que não cheguei a ver nada sobre estar obsoleto ou não.......alias, muitas vezes ignorei essa mesma menção do AndroidStudio por desconhecer um pouco esses pontos. Muito obrigado!